# Quasi multi-perfect numbers

Tags: number-theory

We define a quasi-perfect number as any number n such that $\sigma(n)=2n+1$. No such numbers have been found. Let's say we generalize this and define a quasi-multi-perfect number as any number $n$ such that $\sigma(n)=kn+1$ for some positive integer $k$. Can we find a lower bound for the smallest quasi-multi-perfect number and what properties must a quasi-multi-perfect number have?

Comment: Check this page: http://wwwhomes.uni-bielefeld.de/achim/mpn.html

Comment: that page is about n such that sigma(n)=kn. im asking about n such that sigma(n)=kn+1

Comment: For $k=1$ , we have $\sigma(n)=n+1$ which holds if and only if $n$ is prime. For the case $k>1$ , there is no solution upto $n=10^8$